# set theoretic equivalence in quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

If I am given a ring $R$ and a 2-sided ideal $K\subseteq R$, I know that I have a well-defined quotient ring $R/K$. My question is the following: We know that if we have $a,b\in R$, then $(a+K)+(b+K)=(a+b)+K$. This is exactly a set-theoretic equivalence as well. But if we take $(a+K)\cdot (b+K)=a\cdot b+K$, this is not necessarily a set theoretic equivalence (do not know how to show that $(a+K)\cdot (b+K)\supseteq a\cdot b+K$ for general case). Therefore I claim that if we want it to be real set equivalence, we need to say that $[(a+K)\cdot (b+K)]+K=a\cdot b+K$. Is my observation correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you call "a set theoretic equivalence" as well. The only such equiv. relation I know for sure it exists in this issue, which comes up already in group theory, is $\; a+K=a'+H\iff a-a'\in K\;$ . The operations of sum and multiplication in a quotient ring are defined on equivalence classes and have to be shown well defined.

Comment: What I mean is that when we look at $a+K=a'+K$, we can show that for every $k\in K$, $a+k\in a'+K$ and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, and then what? You need to prove that $$\begin{cases}a+K=a'+K\\{}\\b+K=b'+K\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}(a+b)+K=(a'+b')+K\\{}\\(a+K)(b+K)=(a'+K)(b'+K)\end{cases}$$

Comment: I understand what you say. The only thing I am saying is that $(a+K)(b+K)$ is only a part of the coset $ab+K$ and not the whole coset. That is all I am saying

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you say: we DEFINE $\;(a+K)(b+K):=ab+K\;$ and we then pass to show this definition makes sense, exactly as we do with the sum. Both are abstract operations and both must be shown to be well defined. What do you mean by "part of a coset"? I*t's like saying that since $\;3+7=10\;$, then $\;7\;$ is "a part" of $\;10\;$: in what sense?

Comment: @User666x : how do you _define_ $(a+K)(b+K)$? In general, as Joanpemo said, we have to show that the definition $(a+K)(b+K) := ab +K$ makes sense (knowing that $K$ is a $2$-sided ideal).

Comment: That is exactly what I say. The reasonable thing to do is to define $(a+K)(b+K):=ab+K$. But $ (a+K)(b+K)$ is not a whole coset. That is all I am saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have in mind that we can define $AB = \{ab \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ for $A,B \subseteq R$. Let denote this product by $A \ast B$, just to distinguish it from the product of cosets defined by $(a+K)\cdot (b+K)=ab+K$

Then, if I understand well, you want to compare $(a+K)\cdot (b+K)$ and $(a+K)\ast (b+K)$.

Since $K$ is a $2$-sided ideal of $R$:
$$(a+K)\ast (b+K) = \{(a+k)(b+k') = ab+kb+ak'+kk' \mid k,k' \in K\} \subseteq \{ab+\tilde k \mid \tilde k \in K\} = ab+K$$

However, the reverse inclusion may fail in general. Take $R= \Bbb Z, K=3\Bbb Z,a=0=b$. Then $(a+K)\ast (b+K)=9\Bbb Z$, whereas $(a+K)\cdot (b+K) = 0 + 3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. And it disturbs me that the definition is "=".  (a+K)⋅(b+K)=ab+K

Comment: So you are asking why we define the product of cosets with $\cdot$ and not with $\ast$ ? Well, it is false that defining it with $\ast$ would give a coset as result of the product. My last example gives $9\Bbb Z$ which is not a coset in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I am asking why this definition is correct. I understand that it is a definition. For example, it will look much more reasonable for me to look at it like this: $[(a+K)\cdot (b+K)]+K=a\cdot b + K$.

Comment: @User666x : it has no meaning to write "$[(a+K)\cdot (b+K)]+K$" in this context. You have to start with two cosets, say $u=a+K$ and $v=b+K$. Then you have to define their product $u \cdot v$, i.e. $(a+K) \cdot (b+K)$, so there is no "$+K$" at the end. What you wrote isn't even logical, since $[(a+K)\cdot (b+K)]$ is not an element in $R$, whereas $a \cdot b$ is.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand